# Problem defining new .phtml in layout.xml (checkout_cart_item_default)

Tags: layout, template

I try to "extend" in my module the checkout/cart/item/default.phtml template but do not manage to find the good definition in layout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ...

    <checkout_cart_item_default>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>    
    </checkout_cart_item_default>

</layout>
```

is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no layout handle named "checkout_cart_item_default"
The block definition "checkout.cart" is only under the layout handle "checkout_cart_index". So it should be:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ...

    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            ...
        </reference>    
    </checkout_cart_index>

</layout>
```

I guess you want to set a template for an item. Each line sets a new template for items of a specific product type:

```
<reference name="checkout.cart">
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>downloadable</type><block>downloadable/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>giftvoucher</type><block>giftvoucher/cart_item</block><template>quotemodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```